# Nested components in Vue.js: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm using Vue-CLI and getting this error. It's found in the `<comment>` component.

When the CommentForm's `submitComment()` method fires and adds the comment object to `selfComments` to be rendered out, the error occurs. It might be because they reference each other or something, but I'm not sure.

I've attempted to include only relevant information:

**Edit: I think it's related to this:** https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-have-indirectly-self-nested-components-in-vue-js-2/1931

CommentForm.vue

```
<template>
   ...
        <ul class="self-comments">
            <li is="comment" v-for="comment in selfComments" :data="comment"></li>
        </ul>
   ...
</template>

<script>    
import Comment from 'components/Comment'

export default {
    name: 'comment-form',
    components: {
        Comment
    },
    props: ['topLevel', 'replyTo', 'parentId'],
    data() {
        return {
            text: '',
            postingStatus: 'Post',
            error: false,
            selfComments: []
        }
    },
    methods: {
        submitComment() {
            ...
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
...
</style>
```

Comment.vue

```
<template>
       ...
             <comment-form v-if="replyFormOpen" :top-level="false" :reply-to="data.username" :parent-id="data.id"></comment-form>

             <!-- recursive children... -->
             <ul>
                 <li is="comment" @delete="numComments -= 1" v-for="comment in data.children" :data="comment"></li>
             </ul>

       ...
</template>

** importing CommentForm here seems to cause the issue

<script>
import CommentForm from 'components/CommentForm'

export default {
    name: 'comment',
    components: {
        CommentForm
    },
    props: ['data'],
    data() {
        return {
            deleteStatus: 'Delete',
            deleted: false,
            error: false,
            replyFormOpen: false
        }
    },
    methods: {
        ...
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
...
</style>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you need specify extension when you are loading single file components (.vue files)
`import Comment from 'components/Comment.vue'`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you're running into this issue: [Circular References between Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Circular-References-Between-Components).

In your `CommentForm` component, try registering the `Comment` component during the `beforeCreate()` event. This will help Vue figure out the correct order in which to resolve the components.

```
<script>
export default {
    name: 'comment-form',
    props: ['topLevel', 'replyTo', 'parentId'],
    data() {
        return {
            text: '',
            postingStatus: 'Post',
            error: false,
            selfComments: []
        }
    },
    methods: {
        submitComment() {
            ...
        }
    },
    beforeCreate() {
        // register the Comment component here!!!!
        this.$options.components.Comment = require('components/Comment.vue');
   }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Looks like it's `beforeCreate` not `beforeCreated`. It works though. Thanks!