# Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined. (Vue using plugins)

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm trying to use this [countdown-timer](https://vuejsexamples.com/a-count-down-timer-for-vue-js-framework/) / [on-github](https://github.com/noorzaie/vue-circular-count-down-timer) inside one of my single-file-components.
Even though I'm importing it like mentioned in the example, I'm getting this error:

```
21:27:20.553 [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

found in

---> <CircularCountDownTimer>
       <Visualization> at src/views/Visualization.vue
         <App> at src/App.vue
           <Root> vue.runtime.esm.js:619
    VueJS 17
    run es6.promise.js:75
    notify es6.promise.js:92
    flush _microtask.js:18
```

Looking up the warning I've found the following pages:

[vue-router-problem1](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/713)
[vue-router-problem2](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/1882)

What I've gathered/attempted from that:

- Change vue-cli config to use runtime compiler (No change)

```
22:02:49.722 [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

found in

---> <CircularCountDownTimer>
       <Visualization> at src/views/Visualization.vue
         <App> at src/App.vue
           <Root> vue.esm.js:628
    VueJS 18
    run es6.promise.js:75
    notify es6.promise.js:92
    flush _microtask.js:18
```

- Import in Main.js with Vue.use(Plugin) (Same error)
- Import it in the router component (Same error)

**EDIT:**
I've also looked at this question [nested-components in vuejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42634488/nested-components-in-vue-js-failed-to-mount-component-template-or-render-funct?rq=1)
And changed the component registration like so:

```
    beforeCreate() {
      this.$options.components.CircularCountDownTimer = require('vue-circular-count-down-timer')
    },
```

**None of the above made this plugin work for me and I don't really understand why.**

*Here is my code:*

main.js

```
    import Vue from "vue";
    import App from "./App.vue";
    import router from "./router";
    import CircularCountDownTimer from "vue-circular-count-down-timer";

    Vue.use(CircularCountDownTimer)

    Vue.config.productionTip = false;

    export const eventBus = new Vue();

    new Vue({
      router,
      render: h => h(App)
    }).$mount("#app");
```

component (Visualization.vue):

```
<template>
  <div id="content">
    <circular-count-down-timer
      v-for="counter in counters" :key="counter.id"
      :initial-value="counter.seconds"
      :show-minute="false"
      :show-hour="false"
      :show-negatives="false"
      :second-label="counter.name"
      :steps="1"
    />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import CircularCountDownTimer from "vue-circular-count-down-timer";
export default {
  name: "Visualization",
  components: {
    CircularCountDownTimer
  },
  data() {
    return {
      counters: []
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    if (localStorage.getItem("delays")) {
      try {
        this.counters = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("delays"));
      } catch (e) {
        console.debug(e);
        localStorage.removeItem("delays");
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Also this is the data when reading from localStorage:

```
[{"id":1,"seconds":"60","name":"asdf"}]
```

Dependencies in package.json:

```
    "dependencies": {
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.4",
        "core-js": "^2.6.5",
        "vue": "^2.6.10",
        "vue-awesome-countdown": "^1.0.16",
        "vue-circular-count-down-timer": "^1.0.4",
        "vue-grid-layout": "^2.3.4",
        "vue-router": "^3.0.3"
      }
```

Comment: Why do you pass a String `"counter"` in `Vue.use(CircularCountDownTimer, "counter");`?  Why isn't it just `Vue.use(CircularCountDownTimer);`?

Comment: `import CircularCountDownTimer from "vue-circular-count-down-timer";` points to install method ? its not a component, is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`vue-circular-count-down-timer` is a plugin, so this bit of the code seems to be correct:

```js
import CircularCountDownTimer from "vue-circular-count-down-timer";

Vue.use(CircularCountDownTimer)
```

If you take a look at the source code for the plugin you'll see that all it does is register a component globally called `circular-count-down-timer`:

https://github.com/noorzaie/vue-circular-count-down-timer/blob/master/src/components/index.js

The problem occurs when you do this:

```js
import CircularCountDownTimer from "vue-circular-count-down-timer";
export default {
  name: "Visualization",
  components: {
    CircularCountDownTimer
  },
```

You're just importing the plugin again and then trying to use it as a component. But it isn't a component, it's a plugin. Vue doesn't know this, it just sees an object without a `template` or `render` function.

Get rid of the local component import and it should just use the globally registered component instead.

Comment: @HackXIt It isn't really clear to me why the author of this component chose to expose it as a plugin rather than just as a component. The documentation for it is a little sloppy in its use of the word `component`.

Comment: I switched to https://github.com/mlinquan/vue-awesome-countdown which seems quite more reliable.